# getSupportFragmentManager() error in view

Tags: java, android

Why I am getting an error message showing change
`getSupportFragmentManager()` in `view`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.R;
import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.flycodialog.IOSTaoBaoDialog;
import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.tabbed.Tab1Contact;
import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.tabbed.Tab2Chat;
import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.tabbed.Tab3Online;
import activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.tabbed.TabbedActivity;
import butterknife.Bind;
import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;
import devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by GIGAMOLE on 28.03.2016.
 */
public class HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    private ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener view2;

    private TabbedActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    private FragmentManager FragManager;

    @Bind(R.id.elv)
    ExpandableListView mElv;

    private Context mContext = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_coordinator_ntb);
        initUI();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
                return view.equals(object);
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(final View container, final int position, final Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    try{
                        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                                getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.tabbed_main, null, false);
                        container.addView(view);

                        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//                        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                        toolbar.setOnClickListener(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this);

                        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
                        // primary sections of the activity.
                        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new TabbedActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

                        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
                        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

                        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

                        return view;
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Can't get the fragment manager with this");
                        return null;
                    }
                }else if (position == 2) {
                    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                        getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vp_list, null, false);
                    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
                                    getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false
                            )
                    );
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleAdapter());

                    container.addView(view);
                    return view;
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                            getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.test, null, false);
                    container.addView(view);
                    final TextView txt_test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_test);
                    txt_test.setOnClickListener(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this);
                    return view;
                } else {
                    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                            getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vp, null, false);

                    final TextView txtPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_vp_item_page);
                    txtPage.setText(String.format("Page #%d", position));

                    container.addView(view);
                    return view;
                }
            }
        });

        final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_preview);

        final NavigationTabBar navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);
        final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_first),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                        .title("MyHeart")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_second),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[1]))
                        .title("Cup")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_third),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[2]))
                        .title("Diploma")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fourth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[3]))
                        .title("Flag")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fifth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[4]))
                        .title("Medal")
                        .build()
        );

        navigationTabBar.setModels(models);
        navigationTabBar.setViewPager(viewPager, 2);

        //IMPORTANT: ENABLE SCROLL BEHAVIOUR IN COORDINATOR LAYOUT
        navigationTabBar.setBehaviorEnabled(true);

        navigationTabBar.setOnTabBarSelectedIndexListener(new NavigationTabBar.OnTabBarSelectedIndexListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartTabSelected(final NavigationTabBar.Model model, final int index) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onEndTabSelected(final NavigationTabBar.Model model, final int index) {
                model.hideBadge();
            }
        });
        navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

            }
        });

        final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < navigationTabBar.getModels().size(); i++) {
                    final NavigationTabBar.Model model = navigationTabBar.getModels().get(i);
                    navigationTabBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final String title = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(15));
                            if (!model.isBadgeShowed()) {
                                model.setBadgeTitle(title);
                                model.showBadge();
                            } else model.updateBadgeTitle(title);
                        }
                    }, i * 100);
                }

                coordinatorLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(navigationTabBar, "Coordinator NTB", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9b92b3"));
                        ((TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text))
                                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#423752"));
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }, 1000);

                Toast.makeText(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this, "fab Button Click Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#009F90AF"));
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9f90af"));
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("HorizontalCoordinatorNtb Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

    public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.txt.setText(String.format("Navigation Item #%d", position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView txt;

            public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vp_item_list);
            }
        }
    }


//    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        ViewCompat.animate(v)
                .setDuration(200)
                .scaleX(0.9f)
                .scaleY(0.9f)
                .setInterpolator(new HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.CycleInterpolator())
                .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(final View view) {
//                        Toast.makeText(HorizontalNtbActivity.this, "function onAnimationStart()",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        Log.d("function onAnimationStart", "function");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(final View view) {
                        switch (v.getId()) {
                            case R.id.txt_test:
//                                startActivity(
//                                        new Intent(HorizontalNtbActivity.this, SamplesNtbActivity.class)
//                                );

                                Toast.makeText(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this, "Test Button Click Event",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//Toast.m
                                new SweetAlertDialog(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.CUSTOM_IMAGE_TYPE)
                                        .setTitleText("Sweet!")
                                        .setContentText("Here's a custom image test.")
                                        .setCustomImage(R.drawable.custom_img)
                                        .show();

                                final IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity.this, (View) view2);
                                dialog.show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(final View view) {
                    }
                })
                .withLayer()
                .start();
    }

    private class CycleInterpolator implements android.view.animation.Interpolator {

        private final float mCycles = 0.5f;

        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(final float input) {
            return (float) Math.sin(2.0f * mCycles * Math.PI * input);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Tab1Contact tab1Contact = new Tab1Contact();
                    return tab1Contact;
                case 1:
                    Tab2Chat tab2Chat = new Tab2Chat();
                    return tab2Chat;
                case 2:
                    Tab3Online tab3Online = new Tab3Online();
                    return tab3Online;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "CONTACT";
                case 1:
                    return "CHAT";
                case 2:
                    return "ONLINE";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: are you using fragment?

Comment: `TabbedActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter` is defined where? Please show that class...

Comment: Why are you trying to put a Fragment PagerAdapter within a Fragment, though? That's probably making things more complicated than needed

Comment: if you using fragment, you should do this 'getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: @cricket_007
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {super(fm);}
        
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {}
        
        public int getCount() {}
        
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {}
}

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar Showing message: "Cannot resolve method getActivity()"

Comment: @rama where is you put this code? fragment or activity?

Comment: Please [edit] your question

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar public class HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
protected void onCreate() {}
private void initUI() {
public Object instantiateItem() { // getSupportFragmentManager() in here}}

Comment: @cricket_007 I was edited the question, thanks

Comment: @rama I'm sorry, you don't need 'getActivity()' if you call 'getSupportFragmentManager()' in activity. I assume that error because you don't have context when you call 'getSupportFragmentManager()', try to use 'this' or 'getBaseContext()' before you call 'getSupportFragmentManager()'. e.g 'getBaseContext().getSupportFragment()'

Comment: You added the wrong class, not `TabbedActivity`, where `TabbedActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter` is defined

Comment: @Azis `getBaseContext()` isn't a `FragmentActivity`, where `getSupportFragmentManager()` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity doesn't extend [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) from the support library, therefore you cannot call [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()).

So you need something like that:

```
public class HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and then cast:

```
((HorizontalCoordinatorNtbAndTabbedActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Plus ViewPager inside ViewPager - it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. It could and possibly solve some possible problems.
2. Pass SupportFrogmentManager to FragmentStatePagerAdapter if inside it you are using fragments from support library. In other case - pass FragmentManager.
3. Depending on your view hierarchy you can try to get ChildFragmentManager.
4. Try to move ViewPager from fragment to activity.